# Viewing hidden files on Android Studio's Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android, android-studio, hidden-files, android-device-monitor

I have created a hidden directory for my app and wish to view it on Android Studio's Android Device Monitor, however, ADM does not show the directory. How can I change ADM's preferences to view that folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After read as source code, I find that as commit command "ls -l" to device, so if we want to view the hidden files, you can repo the as source code alter the command to "ls -al", then build the as.

Answer (score 4):

This still seems not to be possible in Android studio without a hack. An alternate method is using adb:

```
adb shell
cd your/desired/directory
ls -a

etc.
```